# ZF1 render a module view into common layout

Tags: zend-framework, layout, view, render, partial

I'm actually trying to create a module in ZF1 which I want to be really "plugin"-like. The main application use the default layout which is located under `data/current/views/layouts`.

First problem, my module, use by default the following layout `application/views/layouts/default.phtml`. What I want is to use the other one (see above). So I did this :

```
public function init() {
    parent::init();
    $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
    $layout->setLayoutPath(DATA_PATH . '/view/layouts');
    $layout->setLayout('common');
}
```

The second problem is that, in this layout (`data/current/views/layouts`), I'm actually rendering some partial views. But when I try to set the layout from the module, I got an error because it can't find those partials (because of the context, it's now trying to load those partial from the module context). I don't want to copy those partials into my module in order to make it works (dirty and not scalable). So the question is : how to just render a module action (controller/action) into the common layout but without any partials errors?

Thanks to all for your help

Comment: If possible I would use Zend Framework 2 as it already has the concept of plug & play modules

Answer (score 0):

below is working in my application I configured this way. It worked perfectly.

```
protected function _initLayout(){
    $layout = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    if(in_array('admin', $layout)){
        $layout_dir = 'admin';
    }else if(in_array('default', $layout)){
        $layout_dir = 'default';
    }else{
        $layout_dir = 'default';
    }
      $options = array(
             'layout'     => 'layout',
             'layoutPath' => APPLICATION_PATH."/modules/".$layout_dir."/views/layouts"
      );
    Zend_Layout::startMvc($options);
}
```

or if you want to us helper so you can also try

```
public function init()
{
     $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('front');
}
```

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but it's not working. As I said, I can actually display the common layout. My problem is that in this common layout, I'm rendering some partial view. When tryin to access this layout from the module, I've got an error because it can't find those partial view (maybe because of the module context). Thanks for your help man, really appreciate

Comment: Yeah, the module is well configured. I can use anything (helpers...). Using the layout from `application/views/layouts/default.phtml` works fine but since the application itself use the one in `data/current/view/layouts` I need to use that one. Again, the goal for me is to make a module not dependent at all from the application